# Why does occur difference origin point in quartz framework?

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics

I've made methods like follow and excute code.

I am confusing about origin of quartz framework after looking follow result image.

Please look at follow code and image.

[in ViewController.m]

Excute a follow method when press UIButton.

```
- (void)test {
    [customView drawCustom];
    [customView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

[in CustomView.m]

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    cgc_Context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(cgc_Context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cgc_Context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(cgc_Context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(cgc_Context, 200, 50);
    CGContextStrokePath(cgc_Context);
}

- (void)drawCustom {
    CGContextSetLineWidth(cgc_Context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cgc_Context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(cgc_Context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(cgc_Context, 200, 50);
    CGContextStrokePath(cgc_Context);
}
```

[Result screen]

Red Line : result of drawRect

Yellow Line : result of drawCustom

Why does occur different origin point?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must read the apple's documentation about [Quartz 2D Coordinate Systems](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC)